# WPF: CLR property to dependency property

Tags: wpf, animation, dependency-properties

I have user control  with property

```
public double X
    {
        get
        {
            return Canvas.GetLeft(this) + this.Radius;
        }
        set
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this, value - this.Radius);
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("X"));
        }
    }
```

I want to use animation related with this property but animation require only dependency property. How i can resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you want "X" to be the centre of your object (Ellipse?)

I can suggest two things:

1. Create a new dependency proeprty and put your setter code in the OnPropertyChanged callback for the new property. (This is probably best)
2. Set a RenderTransform to your element that is a TranslateTransform with -Radius, then setting Canvas.Left will be like setting its centre.

Comment: If you set X to 50 and the radius is 10 in the OnPropertyChanged you will end up setting Canvas.Left to 40. The getter will return the correct 50, no need to change it. If the radius changes just update X = Canvas.Left + Radius

Comment: I don't understand where will be { return Canvas.GetLeft(this) + this.Radius; } logic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all this property does is derive its value from `Canvas.Left`. Why don't you animate `Canvas.Left` directly?